# Is Parse's server down ahead of schedule or am I missing something?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, error-handling, cloud, command-line-interface

I haven't been able to contact Parse's server at all of the past week,
when I try to deploy my Cloud Code, the CLI gives me the following error:

[image]

When I try to add a new Cloud Code I get this error:

[image]

And back in Xcode, when I try to run my application, I get this error:

[image]

What is the issue here? And is there any fix to this?

I See that the errors have a sort of reference to go Lang, what does that have to do with the situation ?

Answer (score 0):

Parse is (obviously) still available (for now!). It looks like an authorization error (i.e. wrong keys setup). Two things:

**1. Update your Parse CLI SDK**

Run an update to grab the latest parse CLI SDK:

```
`$ parse update`
```

**Check your config.json has the correct keys in it**

In your cloud code directory, there is a `config/global.json` file. This is what the ParseSDK uses to authenticate against Parse.com. Check the keys are correct for your app(s):

```
{
  "global": {
    "parseVersion": "1.4.2"
  },
  "applications": {
    "YourAppName": {
      "applicationId": "THE APP KEY HERE",
      "masterKey": "THE MASTER KEY HERE"
    },
    "_default": {
      "link": "YourAppName"
    }
  }
}
```